# Difference between "Present Simple" and "Present Continuous" or "Gerund"

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I have a very confusing exercise in my workbook. There are 4 options. This is the question:
I wouldn't like _____ in bed until noon, although I enjoy _____
1) to lie, to sleep  2) lying, sleeping  3) lying, to sleep  4) to lie, sleeping
I have no idea. Hopefully you can help me.

Greetings

Comment: Greetings, Welcome to the community. Have you done any research online? Please share it with contributors.

Comment: Yes I did some research, but I think there are several options... Sadly there is only one answer correct.

Comment: tell us what you think and why.

Comment: Apart from the actual *title*, where does ***“Present Simple”*** figure in this question? Also, I think from your point of view, ***“Present Continuous”*** and ***“Gerund”*** are probably "the same thing". What you really seem to be asking about is the choice between ***infinitive*** *(to sleep)* and ***gerund*** *(sleeping)* - which has been asked about on ELL many times before.

Comment: See https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/like and https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/enjoy.